# weight not working when inflate layout in another xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

Main.xml file

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel2" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="8"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Here, i am adding below xml file into linearlayout llData ..

inflate_page.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/grid_default" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="4" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

inflate layout in another using below code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View menuLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_page, llData,
                true);
```

Below image is what i want:

[image]

Below image is my actual output:

[image]

please guide me how to solve this problem of weight. layout not showing properly.

Comment: Put your etire xml file.

Comment: There's no problem in your layout. It is coming as U expected

Comment: @AndroidHacker no, its not like that.. you can see difference between two images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the ScrollView. Try to add to the layout setting "fillViewport:true"

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel2" 
        android:fillViewport="true" <---
        >
```

This way the Scrollview will always fill the screen and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your concern @Segi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="4" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So your over all requirement is (1) ImageView at start of app with TV1 to right of it. (2) TV2 at center of screen (3) TV3 at bottom of screen. Am I right?

Comment: Okay looking into your issue